# How do I test ActionFilterAttributes that work with ModelState?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, action-filter, modelstate

As suggested by (among others) Kazi Manzur Rashid in [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx), I am using `ActionFilterAttributes` to transfer model state from one request to another when redirecting.

However, I find myself unable to write a unit test that test the behavior of these attributes. As an example, this what I want the test for the `ImportModelStateAttribute` to do:

1. Setup the `filterContext` so that `TempData[myKey]` contains some fake "exported" `ModelState` (that is, a `ModelStateDictionary` I create myself, and add one error to)
2. Make `ModelState` contain one model error.
3. Call `OnActionExecuting`.
4. Verify the two dictionaries are merged, and `ModelState` now contains *both* errors.

I'm at a loss already on the first step.

**EDIT:**
Yes, I've tried mocking `ActionFilterAttribute` with Moq, but I get errors stating

> Invalid setup on non-overridable member

for both `TempData` and `ModelState`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tomas, You do not have to mock the filterContext, you can create the real object for testing the action filter, the same goes for the model state, these are poco objects. Only thing that you have to mock is the HttpContext (if needed).

```
[Fact]
public void Should_import_complete_view_data()
{
    var attribute = new ImportViewDataFromTempDataAttribute();

    var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    var requestContext = new RequestContext(httpContext.Object, new RouteData());

    var previousModel = new object();
    var previousViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(previousModel) {{"foo", "bar"}};

    previousViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("foo", "bar");

    var controller = new Mock<ControllerBase>();
    controller.Object.ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary();
    controller.Object.TempData = new TempDataDictionary { { attribute.Key, previousViewData } };

    var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(requestContext, controller.Object);
    var actionContext = new ActionExecutingContext(controllerContext, new Mock<ActionDescriptor>().Object, new Dictionary<string, object>());

    attribute.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);

    Assert.True(actionContext.Controller.ViewData.ContainsKey("foo"));
    Assert.True(actionContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.ContainsKey("foo"));
    Assert.Same(previousModel, actionContext.Controller.ViewData.Model);
}
```

Comment: Haha, sometimes we tend to make things harder than they are, don't we? =) My solution: I created a `FakeController` class that inherits `Controller` and added the model state and temp data I wanted. I then mocked the filter contexts and set up the mocks to return my instance of `FakeController`. Works like a charm! Thanks! =)