# Unit testing ModelState ActionFilter

Tags: asp.net, .net, unit-testing, action-filter, modelstate

guys! 
I have this ModelState filter,

```
public class ValidateModelStateFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't have any ideas on how to unit test it.
Any help?

Comment: Create it, call it, verify what is in response?

Comment: Would the ideas from this post help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614855/how-do-i-test-actionfilterattributes-that-work-with-modelstate

Comment: I just posted an answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27861910/292230