# Unit Testing a Custom Validation Filter

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, nunit, moq

I have the following attribute:

```cs
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                    HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have this generic extension method for Determining whether the attribute is applied to a method or not

```cs
public static bool ActionHasFilter(this ApiController controller, string action, Type filter)
    {
        var controllerType = controller.GetType();
        var method = controllerType.GetMethod(action);

        object[] filters = method.GetCustomAttributes(filter, true);

        return filters.Any(x=>x.GetType() == filter);

    }
```

My problem is how do i go about testing whether the attribute actually works or not, without testing the controller action?

Let's say i have the following Entity

```cs
public class UserViewModel
{
     [Required]
     public string Name {get; set;}
     [Required]
     [EmailAddress]
     public string Email {get;set;
}
```

How would i go about mocking the context and checking whether the model is valid?

I'm using Nunit and Moq.

Answer (score 9):

[Spock's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27168828/292230) is on the right track, but is a bit too invasive on the code, because it makes the `ValidateModelAttribute` class dependent on `TestableHttpActionContext`. My implementation uses a public property that will be used to "inject" the `Request` object for the Unit Tests, while the implementation as attribute continues to use the `Request` object from the `ActionContext`:

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public HttpRequestMessage TestRequestMessage { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        PerformValidation(actionContext, TestRequestMessage ?? actionContext.Request);
    }

    private void PerformValidation(HttpActionContext actionContext, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            actionContext.Response = request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

Unit tests:

```
[Test]
public void OnActionExecuting_ValidModel_ResponseIsNotSet()
{
    var actionContext = new HttpActionContext();

    actionContext.ModelState.Clear();

    var attribute = new ValidateModelAttribute { TestRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage() };

    attribute.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);

    Assert.IsNull(actionContext.Response);
}

[Test]
public void OnActionExecuting_InvalidModel_ResponseIsSetToBadRequest()
{
    var actionContext = new HttpActionContext();

    actionContext.ModelState.AddModelError("key", "error");

    var attribute = new ValidateModelAttribute() { TestRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage() };

    attribute.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);

    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.Response.StatusCode);
}
```

Please note that I'm not using an actual model to validate the `ModelState`, because that's out of scope for the Unit Tests: We want to test the `ModelState`'s outcome, not the `ModelState` itself. ;-)

Comment: Great, I also think this is the right way to go. It is shame that too much messing around when some WEB API types is not inherently testable.

Comment: If the filter being tested uses `request.CreateResponse()` be sure to use the overload that includes the `configuration` parameter and provide a `HttpConfiguration TestConfiguration` that is resolved similarly to that above.

Answer (score 0):

You would do this as below.
Couple of things you need to consider.

1. ModelState does not need be stubbed out, you can just Add Model error which causes *actionContext.ModelState.IsValid* to false.

   contextStub.Object.ModelState.AddModelError("key", "error");

   Also you don't required *UserViewModel*
2. You cannot use the Moq to setup actionContext.Request as the Request property is non-virtual. Also it has a getter only you cannot provide your own HttpRequestMessage either.

To get around with this you need to abstract the HttpActionContext and create Virtual property so Moq can provide a setup. A technique can be called *Extract Override*

```cs
public class TestableHttpActionContext : HttpActionContext
{
    public virtual new HttpRequestMessage  Request  { get; set; }
}
```

Now you action method can be modified as below.

```cs
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {            
        TestableActionExecuting((TestableHttpActionContext)actionContext);
    }

    private void TestableActionExecuting(TestableHttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can Unit Test the OnActionExecuting as below.

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Test]
    public void OnActionExecuting_ErrorResponse_ExpectBadRequest()
    {
        var sut = new ValidateModelAttribute();
        var contextStub = new Mock<TestableHttpActionContext>();
        contextStub.Object.ModelState.AddModelError("key", "error");
        contextStub.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(new HttpRequestMessage());

        sut.OnActionExecuting(contextStub.Object);

        Assert.AreEqual("BadRequest", 
                         contextStub.Object.Response.StatusCode.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code will work on the Unit Test, but not on the implemented attribute, because HttpActionContext cannot be cast to TestableHttpActionContext.

Comment: You just need to use HttpActionContext not TestableHttpActionContext. It is just facilitate the testable behavior. Important: TestableHttpActionContext does not have any behavior and only use for testing.

Comment: I know, but your code doesn't work in production. When OnActionExecuting is triggered with a regular HttpActionContext, it will throw an exception because it cannot be cast to TestableHttpActionContext.

Comment: Sorry I missed that. Thanks for pointing out. I think @Prutswonder answer/direction is more appropriate for me.